# backbutton event not working on Intel XDK Crosswalk app

Tags: intel-xdk

I put code below in my XDK project. I use onsenUI and Angular. Everything works great in the emulator but the Crosswalk app doesn't trigger this during backbutton event.

Is there anything else that needs to be done? I can't find anything specific about this in the documentation. Thanks.

```
<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener ("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

    function onBackKeyDown () {

        // Handle the back button
        console.log("back");
        //other codes here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As a workaround, could you try using the 'intel.xdk.device.hardware.back' event and see if that works?

Comment: This may be a bug in the Crosswalk Cordova plugin framework. Confirm that you can make your code work properly in the Cordova build system first, so you know you've got it written correctly. If that code does not work in Crosswalk, it is likely an issue with the Crosswalk Cordova plugin framework.

Comment: Thanks OldGeeksGuide and @xmnboy. Found the solution and posted as answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you need to have this complete triggers for it to work:

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        function onLoad() {
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
           // Register the event listener
           document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
        }

        // Handle the back button
        //
        function onBackKeyDown() {
           // Handle the back button
        }
```

Comment: Having nearly same problem but your answer is not working. Check out at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34511358/3170029

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function directly to intercept back button

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.hardware.back", function() {

         // write your code
    }, false);
```