# Android Back Button Exiting Apps Instead Of Running Its New Code

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, intel, intel-xdk

I am making an app for Android using HTML-JavaScript on Intel-XDK. I'm overriding the Android Back Button function and Android Menu Button using the following code.

```
<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Android Back Button
----------------------------------------------- */
function backButtonPressed() {
    isPaused = true; // To Pause        
}
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonPressed, false);

/* Android Menu Button
----------------------------------------------- */
function menuButtonPressed() {
    isPaused = false; // To false
}
document.addEventListener("menubutton", menuButtonPressed, false);
</script>
```

Both are working perfectly in Intel-XDK Emulate. But when I am running them in an android device, the menu button code is working but back button code is not working and it's exiting the app. What to do to stop this behavior (ie, exiting the app) and start running my own code?

Note: I also tried code from https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493108 but still not working in Mobile and is working in Emulator.

Comment: @Akhil Need reply not editing... :P

Comment: Try `onBackKeyDown` instead, see the [official Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html). The XDK is simply a front-end for building Cordova apps. Search for Cordova solutions and you'll find XDK solutions.

Comment: I had mixed results.  It worked in the emulator, but not in the DEBUG tab.  When I built the app, it worked (both Crosswalk and regular Android apps).  Are you testing in the debugger or have you built the app?

Comment: @xmnboy `onBackKeyDown` is just a name of your `yourCallbackFunction` so you can use anything here...

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide Yes, Same here. Its work in emulator but when I debug in my Android via USB then its not working. I didnt try it anywhere else so you say that its the bug in Intel-XDK Debug Mode...???

Comment: It looks that way to me.  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Oops... you're right, Muhammad, I mixed up my parameter list! :( You're in good hands with @OldGeeksGuide, he knows what to do. :)

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide Thanks for helping...

Comment: @xmnboy I also tried using the default function name too... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution of this problem and that is the popup that I was ignoring.

[image]

In short, App Preview, Emulator or the Debug Tab are not perfect to give you the perfect answer so take decisions after building the APK and installing it on your device.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run your code on real devices or emulators which are using Intel microprocessors. Maybe it must be compiler optimization problem, which are not optimizing to same level for non Intel microprocessors as mentioned in the [optimization notice](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimization-notice#opt-en). Try to run it on Intel microrocessor AVD (Android Virtual Device). You can make one as mentioned in the [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#apps).

Comment: Ignore that optimization notice at the bottom of every page, it's there as the result of an unrelated lawsuit that requires the posting and has absolutely nothing to do with Intel XDK or Cordova apps.

Comment: The apps you create with the Intel XDK are not compiled, so any such optimization would not apply. They are packaged Cordova apps, using standard Cordova CLI. The problem being encountered by @MuhammadHassan is something else...